# What is the difference between method Sheet1.ShowAll and Sheet1.AutoFilter.ShowAll

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro to clear filter and show all row data. Result is Sheet1.ShowAll. I use this method for long time but sometimes I got error that I can fix using Sheet1.AutoFilter.ShowAll. Why is Sheet1.AutoFilter.ShowAll working?

I use and tested on Excel 2010

```
Sheet1.ShowAll 'runtime error

Sheet1.AutoFilter.ShowAll 'no error, why?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sheet1.ShowAllData` is the code you are looking for to **clear the Filter**.

But if you use `Sheet1.UsedRange.AutoFilter` , it will **remove the filter** or add the filter if no filter is applied.